# Routes based role management in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, permissions, roles, rails-routing

I was building a user role management system. It has a `Permission` model and a `Role` model. `Role has_many permissions` and `User has_many roles`. So we need  CRUDs for `permsissions` and `roles`.

I am thinking about a different approach. How about taking all the routes in my application and create permissions out of it?? Basically permissions are permissions to go to a path, and we have a list of paths in the routes.

I was able to get all the routes in my application like

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a
```

But I could not see this approach implemented anywhere. What are your thoughts on this? Please share your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're describing is the perfect use-case for [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). With it, you define an ability class

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # See the wiki for details:
    # https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities
    if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
    elsif user.contributor?
        can :manage, [Post]
    else
        can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Which can then be used to control access at the controller level

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

This will allow *admins* and *contributors* to access all actions (since admins can manage all resources while contributors can manage posts) while other users will only have access to **read** only actions (index, show). You can of course control access at the resource level too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bart. But how can I add a an Ability from the user end other than coding it? I want it like an admin can select a few permissions from a check list and save them as a role, so that users can be assigned those roles. Is it possible using cancancan?

Comment: cancancan is specifically centred around the *abilities* of a particular user. How those abilities are defined is up to you. That being said, you can easily adapt it to fit your needs. For example, within the ability class, you can do the following `if user.role.permissions.include?(:whatever)` to decide which resources the user has access to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impose permission on per-route basis, create methods for each roles in `application_controller` which checks whether the user has respective permission on it and redirects or whatsover. Use it on `before_action` of your desired controllers and actions..

Comment: That makes it hard when you add a new role, because you will have to write a code for that. Doesn't it?

Comment: If you'd want to go into each route level access control yes. If new role comes along, you just have to add to before_action where you'd want to restrict.. with little tweaks you don't have to write individual method for individual roles at all.

Comment: That makes me to write code everytime I add a route. I want an admin to select permissions from a UI, without any help from a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked https://github.com/ryanb/cancan ? With this gem you can define roles in multiple Models and handle forbidden resources

Comment: How can I let a user add/edit permissions in a role and assign that to a user using cancan? or, how can i generate Abilities from the user end?

Comment: @mukesh if have a permission field in the model, even in another table you can use this and combine with cancan like Bart Jedrocha told you before.